# Pulling specific words out of a line of a text file in python

Tags: python, networking, default, gateway

I'm a newbie python programmer and I'm doing some playing around with network coding. In order to check to see whether a connection to the default gateway of my router has occurred, I want to pull the gateway from my ipaddr file and turn it to a variable, however I can't get it to pull the column from a specific line, only the first line.

This is my code so far:

```
with open('ipaddr.txt', "r") as f:
    line=f.readlines()
    columns = [line.rstrip("\t") for line in f]
    print (line[22])
    print (line[18])
    print (line[26])
    f.close()
```

I want it to pull from column 39 onward on each of the above lines.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not obvious what you want, what you have and how you expect to get there with what you've done. Please **give example input and output** needed and *explain* what you've been trying to do to achieve this.

Comment: use ``c.seek(offset[, whence])`` to move the pointer upto the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `rstrip` where you should be using `split`. You are also reading the file twice `readlines()` and `for line in f`.

```
with open('ipaddr.txt', "r") as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
    table = [line.split("\t") for line in lines]
    print table[22][39:]
    print table[18][39:]
    print table[26][39:]
    f.close()
```